# Cannot find files that should be inside my running docker container

Tags: docker, angr

I'm doing some work with the reverse engineering tool angr, and I'm trying to run it in a container.
My current directory looks likes this:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/ethHack/wetransfer-85179d/Export$ ls
angry.py                 impossible_password_location.csv  report.md
impossible_password.bin  impossible_password_strings.txt   test.txt
```

I then run a specific angr image like so:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/ethHack/wetransfer-85179d/Export$ sudo docker run -it --rm -v $pwd:/local angr/angr
```

Where I believe that using `$pwd:/local` should give me acces to the before shown files inside the container (following [this][1] guide [5:40]).

I run the container, and try to write some python:

```
(angr) angr@38b067fffc2d:~$ ipython3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import angr

In [2]: angr.Project("/impossible_password.bin")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3f794a899665> in <module>
----> 1 angr.Project("/impossible_password.bin")

~/angr-dev/angr/angr/project.py in __init__(self, thing, default_analysis_mode, ignore_functions, use_sim_procedures, exclude_sim_procedures_func, exclude_sim_procedures_list, arch, simos, engine, load_options, translation_cache, support_selfmodifying_code, store_function, load_function, analyses_preset, concrete_target, **kwargs)
    124             self.loader = cle.Loader(thing, **load_options)
    125         elif not isinstance(thing, str) or not os.path.exists(thing) or not os.path.isfile(thing):
--> 126             raise Exception("Not a valid binary file: %s" % repr(thing))
    127         else:
    128             # use angr's loader, provided by cle

Exception: Not a valid binary file: '/impossible_password.bin'
```

where it can't find the file. Same goes for `local/impossible_password.bin"`. How do I get the files of my current direcotry to be available when I spin up the container?
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dQFM5O4KFk